# Object-oriented checkout process design

Tags: php, oop

My colleague and I have been talking for the past 2 hours, trying to work out the best way to design the aspect of our new online shop that deals with a customer's shopping basket, and I'm still not sure that we've come to a great conclusion.

It sounds like a fairly elementary problem, but we've found that actually there is a huge amount of interdependency between different parts of the system.

The parts (so far!) are:

- Shopping basket (tracks what products customers have selected to purchase).
- Deals (defines promotions for products such as "Buy 3 of x for £20", or "Buy 2 of x and get 1 free").
- Low order fee (under a certain value, an additional fee is added to the order).
- Shipping fees (based on a series of options).
- Voucher redemption.
- Customer credits (a customer might have a credit on their account, which would be subtracted from the order total).

I'm very nervous about all these objects talking to each other and getting values from one another, then acting on those values. I'm imagining it'll turn into a big, complex, unmaintainable house of cards.

I'm sure that it's bad practise to have the different parts of my system talking directly to each other, let alone allowing them change each other's state (regardless of how they're doing that), as parts of the system end up relying on other parts being in different states when they run, and if they can all talk to each other, I can't be certain something hasn't changed something else I'm relying on.

But there are lots of examples where I can't see any other way. For example:

- A "Buy X, get Y free" kind of deal needs to add the Y product to the basket when the customer checks out with X in their basket. So deals effectively looks and AND affects the basket.
- Working out whether to apply a low order fee is based on the value of the products in the basket, but AFTER multibuy discounts (3 for the price of 2, for example). So it needs to look at the basket, while also taking into account the deals.
- The basket also needs to display a total value while the customer is browsing the site, and that total should take into account product-related deals, but nothing else.

How can I achieve this kind of thing, without shooting myself in the foot and writing code that could affect tons of other code in unexpected ways?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd suggest you take a look into S.O.L.I.D. Also if you're going TDD you should be pretty safe that it does not just breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you have the following abstract entities:

- Basket
- Deal
- Fee (low order, shipping)
- Credit (voucher, outstanding credit)

You could probably wrap those concepts into a single business logic class which uses a number of gateways to access the concrete models. At first glance, the business logic looks to be "add any deals to the basket, apply any fees, then redeem any credit options." Each of those components appears to be a collection of decorators, each of which have a potential to act on the basket.

It would be the job of the business logic class here to take each of the gateways (Deal, Fee, Credit) and iterate over their individual components. Each component would be passed the basket and asked if it should affect it. If the basket should be affected, the effect should be applied and the iteration can continue.

In this way, the business logic is kept in one place, which defines the order of operation. Each component is loosely coupled the basket via the business logic.

**Update**: [A possible approach](http://yuml.me/dc1be595).